# How do I give a group 'service httpd graceful' permission in sudoers without passwd prompt?

Tags: centos, services, sudo, httpd, sudoers

I'm currently trying to lock down my users a bit. I've created some users:

- `www.foo`
- `www.bar`

and a group:

- `apacheadmins`

Both `www.foo`, and `www.bar` are members of the `apacheadmins` group. They do not currently have sudo access, but I would like to grant them sudo access for:

- `service httpd configcheck`
- `service httpd restart`
- `service httpd graceful`

I've added the following lines, using visudo at the very bottom of the sudoers file:

```
### Setting permissions for www.* users
Cmnd_Alias APACHECMDS = /sbin/service httpd configcheck, /sbin/service httpd graceful, /sbin/service httpd restart
%apacheusers ALL = NOPASSWD: APACHECMDS
```

I would like these users to be able to use these commands without password prompt, but they have key only access, and don't currently have passwords assigned to them.

Whenever I save my changes, open a new bash session as `www.foo` or `www.bar`, I am still greeted with a password prompt.

I've played with it a bit, and I can get it to work if I specify the full path, ie:

`sudo service httpd graceful` does not work.
`sudo /sbin/service httpd graceful` does work.

Can I get this to work without specifying the full path?

**EDIT**: I'm using:

```
[foo@bar~]$ uname -a
Linux bar 2.6.18-164.el5 #1 SMP Thu Sep 3 03:28:30 EDT 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[foo@bar~]$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 5.4 (Final)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the users' `$PATH` variable doesn't include `/sbin`, and so `sudo` isn't actually finding the command.

```
$ sudo service acpid status
[sudo] password for mgorven: 
$ sudo /sbin/service acpid status
acpid (pid 3185) is running...
$ echo $PATH
/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin
$ export PATH=$PATH:/sbin:/usr/sbin
$ sudo service acpid status
acpid (pid 3185) is running...
```

Add `/sbin` to the users' `$PATH` to solve this.